# Is there an existing solution in Rails, ActiveRecord, or a gem, for getting the timestamp of the latest change to any associated record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Let's say I have:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bar
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

Also assume that the `Bar` class has timestamp fields (the ones that are automatically updated when the record is updated).

**Question:** Is there existing functionality/method calls in Rails, ActiveRecord, or a gem somewhere that allows me to call a method that will tell me most recent value in the  `updated_at` columns in any of the records, in any of the associations defined on the `Foo` class?

So, a theoretical `foo.latest_change_to_associated_objects` method should give me a timestamp of when the latest `updated_at` field is for any of my associated records (in this case, for any `Bar` record).

The simplest case, where you have a parent class and just one association is simple enough - a callback or two would do the trick. I'm curious about situations where a class has many associations defined. Is there a gem (or functionality already inside of ActiveRecord that I'm missing) that allows me to declare any/all of my associations to have this functionality?

Obviously I could do a SQL call to figure this out, but I don't want to do that every time I check for the latest change. It seems like there should be a callback chain the automatically updates a `latest_change_on_association` field (or whatever you want to call it) on the parent when any associated record is changed, such that retrieving the latest change timestamp is a matter of checking a single field on the parent record.

**Note:** I looked into http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Observer.html, but the problem there is that I'd have to write an observer for every class. It'd be great if the automation of creating the observers from a list of associations was already wrapped up in a gem or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:touch` to automatically update the `updated_at` timestamp (or *any other timestamp field*) of a parent record of a `belongs_to` when one of its associated records changes:

Emphasis is mine:

> :touch
>
> If true, the associated object will be touched (the updated_at/on attributes set to now) when this record is either saved or destroyed. **If you specify a symbol, that attribute will be updated with the current time** in addition to the updated_at/on attribute.

If you really want to use your `last_association_updated_at` column, you can:

```
belongs_to :parent_class, :touch => :last_association_updated_at
```

See the [Rails Guide on Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to-label-Options).

Comment: Realized this ultimately won't work for my particular situation, but wanted to thank you for the info. It definitely looks like the only thing built into the platform (other than `ActiveModel::Observer`) that might work. I will probably have to use this + some extra stuff to get what I really need on this particular project.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding a column to the table for the parent class which would hold the timestamp of the latest change.  Let's call the column "last_association_updated_at".  Then use the `:touch` option on the association in each child class.  Any time a child record is created, modified or deleted the `last_association_updated_at` column will get updated with the current time.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bar
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo, :touch => :last_association_updated_at
end

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo, :touch => :last_association_updated_at
end
```